# Is it possible to use the google my business API to get location data from locations that you do not own?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-my-business-api

I am currently researching the possibilities of the Google My Business API.

I understand that I need to be an owner/manager of a business/location in order to edit the information. But if I just want to Get the information, such as opening hours, is this possible without being a manager/owner?

Answer (score 0):

No, because you need to have the ClientId, and username, password in case you are working just in playground and if you wanna read this kinda info in Java/python etc. you need client_secrets.json file which is again needed for you to have all authentications.
you can read more **here** [https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup].

in order to access the playground **click here** [https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via the Business Profile APIs.

However, it would be possible via the Places API by making a Place Details request and requesting the opening_hours field: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details